# Count number of 1s in a subarray when array is generated from a single number

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I am looking at this coding problem:

> For a given number *n*, form a list and insert the following pattern into the list at the same position sequentially:
>
> `{ floor(n/2), n%2, floor(n/2) }`
>
> ...until every element in the list is either 1 or 0. Now, calculate the number of 1s in the range from *l* to *r* (1-indexed).
>
> #### Explanation
>
> Start from *n*. Then make a list with the following three elements: `{ floor(n/2), n%2, floor(n/2) }`. Now expand -- **in-place** -- both of those 2 outer elements, considering the new *n* to be `floor(n/2)` .
>
> This process will go on until the value of *n* reduces down to 1 or 0. So it will basically form a tree with 3 branches coming out of every node at every level starting from 1 node (*n*) at the root.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> Three integers: *n, l, r*
>
> #### Constraints
>
> *0 ≤ n < 10<sup>12</sup>,*
> *0 ≤ r - l ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>,*
> *1 ≤ l ≤ r*
>
> #### Output Format
>
> A single line containing the number of 1s in the given range.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> 9 6 9
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> 3

I tried to store every number, but run out of memory. How can I calculate the sum of the range without visiting every node?

Answer (score 1):

The array can be seen as the in-order sequence of a binary tree, which would also be the tree of recursion if you would apply a naive algorithm.

That binary tree has the following properties:

- It is [perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)
- Its height *h* corresponds to the number of binary digits needed to represent *n*. So in the case of 9 (0b1001), *h* = 4.
- It has *2<sup>h</sup>-1* nodes, which is also the number of elements in the array representation.
- Nodes at depth *i* of the tree, all have the same value and correspond to the *i <sup>th</sup>* least significant bit of *n*. Let's call this bit *n<sub>i</sub>* with *i* in [1, *h*].
- By consequence the total value of all nodes together is the sum of 2<sup>i-1</sup>*n<sub>i</sub>* for *i* in [1, *h*], which is exactly *n*.
- A left (or right) subtree of a node at depth *i*, will correspond to the tree you would get for *floor(n/2<sup>i</sup>)*.

To find the node corresponding to index *j* (when 1-based), you would take the binary representation of *j* using exactly *h* binary digits (prepadded with "0" if necessary) and then
as long as that representation has more than one "1" in it, choose the left branch when the left-most digit is "0", and right otherwise. Then remove that digit and repeat.

We could then determine what the value is of each left subtree that is omitted when a move to the right is made, include the 1 in the node itself, and take the total of those values.
This total would represent the number of 1 values *at the left* of index *j*.
This in turn could be used to know the total of 1 values in any range.

Turned into an algorithm, you would get something like the snippet below. You can run it, enter the values for *n, i, j* and see the resulting sum:

```js
function sumBetween(n, i, j) {
    if (j < i) return sumBetween(n, j, i); // put range in ascending order
    return sumUntil(n, j) - sumUntil(n, i - 1);
}

function sumUntil(n, i) {
    let numDigits = n.toString(2).length;
    let bitMask = 1 << numDigits;
    if (i >= bitMask) i = bitMask - 1; // Reduce i when exceeding the "array" size
    if (i < 0) i = 0;

    let sum = 0;
    for (bitMask >>= 1; i > 0 && bitMask > 0; bitMask >>= 1) {
        let goRight = i & bitMask; // Extract a bit from i
        let nodeValue = n % 2; // Get value at current node of binary tree
        n >>= 1; // Go down one level in the tree
        if (goRight) sum += nodeValue + n; // Add node value and values in omitted left subtree
        i -= goRight; // Clear bit in i
    }
    return sum;
}

// I/O handling
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
let result = document.querySelector("span");

document.addEventListener("input", refresh);

function refresh() {
    let [n, i, j] = Array.from(inputs, input => input.value).map(Number);
    let sum = sumBetween(n, i, j);
    result.textContent = sum;
}
refresh();
```

```css
input { width: 4em }
```

```html
n: <input type="number" value="9"><br>
i: <input type="number" value="6"><br>
j: <input type="number" value="9"><br>
sum: <span></span>
```

The algorithm for getting the sum of a range has a time complexity of *O(logn)*, independent of the values for *i* and *j*. The space complexity is *O(1)* -- there's no need to populate an array.